# Unity RenderTexture coordinate system origin is bottom-left on iPad, but top-left on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, textures, coordinate-systems

I'm using [RenderTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html) to take screenshots in my Unity game.

I have successfully managed to draw the Camera contents to the target `RenderTexture` and grab part of the `RenderTexture`'s contents (i.e.: A Region Of Interest) using the code below:

```
RenderTexture currentActiveRT = RenderTexture.active;

var renderTex = new RenderTexture ((int)renderTexSize.x, (int)renderTexSize.y, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);

CameraScreenshot.targetTexture = renderTex;
CameraScreenshot.gameObject.SetActive (true);
CameraScreenshot.Render ();

RenderTexture.active = renderTex;

// 4. Create the final output Texture, which will have the the ROI drawn in the final size.
var tex = new Texture2D ((int)screenshotSize.x, (int)screenshotSize.y, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
tex.ReadPixels (fROI, 0, 0, true);

// 5. Restore context and release resources.
RenderTexture.active = currentActiveRT;
```

Everything works as expected on both the Unity Editor and the iPad device, however, on my iPhone 5S device the final output gets wrong because a different region of the `RenderTexture` is used. After some debugging I realised that on both Editor and iPad the origin of the `RenderTexture` coordinate system is **bottom-left** (upwards) but on the iPhone it is **top-left** (downwards).

Does anyone know how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Unity 5.2.3p3 and the problem is caused by the Metal vs OpenGL differences: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rendertexture-coordinate-system-origin-is-bottom-left-on-ipad-but-top-left-on-iphone-5s.375009/